# Sloped plane: congruent angles (high school)

Tags: soft-question, euclidean-geometry, triangles, education, angle

I know that:

> two parallel straight lines cut by a transversal form pairs of angles that enjoy particular relationships between them, and that have specific names.
> A transversal in cutting two parallel lines identifies alternate internal angles, alternate external angles, internal conjugate angles, external conjugate angles and corresponding angles.

I have to prove that for this image that $\angle A''C''B''\cong \angle ACB$.

[image]

**My proof**:

To decompose the weight force or gravitational force, we need to know what angle it forms with the downward slope. So let's look at the figure and notice two right triangles:

- The triangle $\triangle ABC$ the *cathetus* $d$ and $h$ with hypotenuse $s$. Where $h$ is the height of the slope and $s$ its length, the angle $\angle CAB$ is right, the angle $\angle BCA$ is $\alpha$ and the angle $\angle ABC$ is $\pi/2-\alpha$;
- The triangle $\triangle A''C''B''$ has hypotenuse $\mathbf{F}_g$ and the *cathetus* $\mathbf{F}_s$ and $\mathbf{F}_d$.

First we see that the angle in $\hat{B}'$ is equal to $\hat{B}$, because they are corresponding angles of the parallel lines passing through $AB$ and $A'B'$ cut by the transversal passing through $BC$.

Then we see that the angle in  $\hat{B}''$ is equal to  $\hat{B}'$, because they are interior alternate angles of the parallel lines passing through $BC$ and $A''B'$ cut by the line passing through $B'C'$. From the criteria of similarity we know that if two trinagles have two coincident angles then they are similar. From the first criterion of similarity of triangles we know that:

> Two triangles are similar if and only if they have a congruent angle and the two sides adjacent to it are proportional to each other according to the same constant $k$.

Since I suspect they do not remember or to find difficult my explanation is there a simple, alternative way to prove that $\angle ACB\cong \angle A''C''B''$ in the inclined plane problem?

> *Someone have any other idea?*

Comment: They have their rays perpendicular on each other.

Comment: @sirous Hii sirous :-) I have understood your comment. One ray it is the direction of the height that it is the same the ray of the $\mathbf{P}$ height-force (second ray).

Comment: Please find a way to incorporate your proof without the diagram. If necessary it is enough to mention the theorems you use and the steps. IMO certainly none of the relations you mention *immediately* apply here, since the angles are not related by a single setup of two parallel lines and one transversal, it's more complicated than that. You can use some pointers, because despite your last comment I think the downvote is for a lack of attempt.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Hi, generally I put my explanations: see my questions. Thank you for your comment and advice.

Comment: @Sebastiano Of course I see that you usually put attempts, I was just trying to intuit both the idea behind the downvote and attempting the question. Surely a solution would be the ray ending with $p$ is perpendicular to the line with length $b$ and the ray ending with $p_n$ is perpendicular to the line of length $L$. Then the exterior angle theorem with the triangle formed by $p,b,L$ along with the second observation will give the result.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I have added my explanation. Unfortunately, I have to be concise because I have little time and I am always dealing with documents and administrative papers, especially for the school.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Hi, excuse me very much. Please, do you could convert your code with a complete explanation? I not understood the downvotes. Best regards.

Comment: @Sebastiano My answer matches *exactly* with what you wrote, now that I see it. In fact , I saw my notation and realized that I basically had the same proof as you. I'm also struggling to see a simpler explanation. The basic reason why I'm struggling, is that the two angles don't lie on the same transversal and don't even share vertices or incident rays. The only thing that relates them, is the fact that they are both part of right-angles triangles, and their opposite non-right angles are interior alternate. I mean, it seems to be that straightforward.

Comment: I also tried moving around points (like sliding the block behind and so on, so I could make some lines coincide and create a simpler situation) but it seems I'm doomed here. I'm really sorry that my attempt coincided with yours, but I'm hopefully justifying why it did in the previous comment. That's my main concern, though, that it doesn't happen in one step.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thank you very much for your efforts. My always best regards from the Sicily.

Comment: @Sebastiano Welcome (and thanks for visiting the other post on finite sets being compact!) I know what a pain it is to explain geometry to children, especially if the visual thinking is not very strong. I'm also kind of extremely unhappy with Indian teaching, because all they do is introduce random concepts and don't even elaborate on WHY this/that is being taught. It's just concept, practice question, test, and much later, exam.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I'm totally agree with you.

Comment: @Sebastiano I haven't lost interest in this question from a point of view of how one would teach this to children , but I don't know if the conversation will change from math to math education, which is something I'm a little more soft in! I hope that the math educators site will like your question and give you better explanations on how you can explain this to children, because making these identifications and so on, it's a very large job for children. But for geometry, I always think if you can try and make a "video" proof of the concept it's great, like "angles" moving on top of each other.

Comment: Of course, I can't think of how the video would look, but in my opinion videos are the BEST tool for those with geometric troubles.